# Grouping of clusters in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to cluster data in pandas and while groupby works for most problems I am stuck to find a solution for grouping clusters.

Given a dataframe such as

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4,5], 'y':[1,4,9,16,25], 'valid':[0,1,1,0,1]})

for value, group in df.groupby(by='valid'):
   print(value)
   print(group)
```

This allows to split the data into two groups:

```
   valid  x   y
0      0  1   1
3      0  4  16

   valid  x   y
1      1  2   4
2      1  3   9
4      1  5  25
```

How can I modify this to get three distinct groups where the groups are determined by continuous ranges of the 'valid' column? E.g.:

```
   valid  x   y
0      0  1   1

   valid  x   y
3      0  4  16

   valid  x   y
1      1  2   4
2      1  3   9

   valid  x   y
4      1  5  25
```

Is there something like group from clusters in Pandas?

Comment: why third group is different from second?

Comment: Do you mean continuous range of the x or y column?

Comment: I mean that the 'valid' column contains two clusters of ones, and two clusters of zeros. So I would like to split the dataframe into these clusters. Continuous in the sense that a cluster is given by a range of constant and identical values in the 'valid' column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)d column with [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) (`!=`) and add [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for consecutive groups `Series`:

```
for value, group in df.groupby(df['valid'].ne(df['valid'].shift()).cumsum()):
   print(value)
   print(group)

1
   valid  x  y
0      0  1  1
2
   valid  x  y
1      1  2  4
2      1  3  9
3
   valid  x   y
3      0  4  16
4
   valid  x   y
4      1  5  25
```

**Detail**:

```
print(df['valid'].ne(df['valid'].shift()).cumsum())

0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    4
Name: valid, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought about shift but then got stuck. The idea that the cumulative sum is the same for each cluster is great.